# How to Run 2 Javascript Block in Sync way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have come to a scenario where  i need to run below scenario. I am ready with my code just need to execute both javascript block in sync.

```
var baseQuery ='test';
var mainQuery ='test';
if(baseQuery!='')
{
  //Ajax call
}

if(mainQuery!='')
{
  //Ajax Call
}
```

How i can make sure that second code of block runs if first complete its execution.

Comment: take a look to $q https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a promise, and resolve it in your first ajax call success.

```
var defer = $.Deferred();
var baseQuery ='test';
var mainQuery ='test';
if(baseQuery!='')
{
  //resolve the promise in the success of first ajax call
  defer.resolve(...) // do it inside your success handler in error you can reject
}

if(mainQuery!='')
{
    defer.promise().then(function(data){
         //this will execute after complete of first ajax call;
    })
}
```

you can putt the logic inside your success handler of second block, and inside check for `mainQuery!=''` and then execute the conditional code.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the library you are using to implement AJAX. However, AJAX calls usually operate with **promises**, therefore you just need to call the second function on the resolution block of the first AJAX request.

For example, if you are using **jQuery**, here is how you could do it:

```
$.ajax({
        url: API_URL + "/endpoint",
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function (data) { //This happens after the AJAX promise has resolved
        //call second block here
    })
    .fail(function(e){ //This block is called in case of error in AJAX query
        console.log(e);
    });
})
```

Edit: This ajax query goes inside `if(baseQuery!=''){}`

Comment: problem is that either query can be blank as well so can't put that in success block of first . Because suppose if first condition will be false then it will not execute second as well

Comment: Then all you have to do is write an else statement after your first if and inside it write your second block, so that either you first perform first block and call second in AJAX success, or you dont perform your first block code and directly run second block.

Answer (score 0):

```
var baseQuery ='test';
var mainQuery ='test';
var bool=false;
if(baseQuery!='')
{
  //Ajax call
 //Ajax success (bool=true;)
}
if(mainQuery!='' && bool ==true)
{
  //Ajax Call
}

var baseQuery ='test';
var mainQuery ='test';
var bool=false;
if(baseQuery!='')
{
  //Ajax call
 //Ajax success (if(mainQuery!=''))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run second block on success of first ajax call like this

```
if(baseQuery!='')
{
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,                    
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {                       
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(mainQuery!='')
            {
               //Ajax Call
              $.ajax({
              });
            }
        }
    });
}
```